# JS Jquery syntax for adding optgroup to fields labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, optgroup

I am working on building a nested expression builder. For the first step, I have a long OPTION list (small sample of the list provided below).

What I am currently getting in the dropdown
[image: current dropdown]

[image: target result dropdown]
What I am aiming to create in the dropdown

How would I go about writing an OPTGROUP in the following:

```
function initializeConditions() {
    conditions.conditionsBuilder({
    fields: [      
        {label: "Name", name: "nameField", operators: [
            {label: "is present", name: "present", fieldType: "none"},
            {label: "is blank", name: "blank", fieldType: "none"},
            {label: "is equal to", name: "equalTo", fieldType: "text"},
            {label: "is not equal to", name: "notEqualTo", fieldType: "text"},
        ]},

        {label: "Age", name: "ageField", operators: [                                            
            {label: "is present", name: "present", fieldType: "none"},
            {label: "is blank", name: "blank", fieldType: "none"},
            {label: ...so on & so on...
        ]},

        {label: "Member Attribute", name: "membAttributeField", options: membAttributeOptions, operators: [
            {label: "Age", name: "ageField", fieldType: "select"},
            {label: "Birthday", name: "birthdayField", fieldType: "select"},
            {label: "Gender", name: "genderField", fieldType: "select"},
            {label: "Suburb", name: "suburbField", fieldType: "select"},
            ...,
            ...,
            ...,
            {label: "Email", name: "emailField", fieldType: "select"},
        ]

    ],
    data: {"all": [
        {name: "nameField", operator: "equalTo", value: "Ron Burgundy"},
        {name: "ageField", operator: "greaterThanEqual", value: "43"}
    ]}
  });
}
```

OK, so you can see that I've got this list of fields, operators and options(and var (sub-operators not included in sample)). Here's what I'd like to do...

- I would rather create "Member Attribute" as an opt group
- This would allow me to carry on with creating operators and options:var[],operators for each option inside the OPTGROUP

  ```
  {label: "Member Attribute", name: "membAttributeField", options: membAttributeOptions, operators: [
      {label: "Age", name: "ageField", fieldType: "select"},
      {label: "Birthday", name: "birthdayField", fieldType: "select"},
      {label: "Gender", name: "genderField", fieldType: "select"},
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      {label: "Email", name: "emailField", fieldType: "select"},
  ]
  ```

Example of how the output should be presented in HTML

```
<select name"membAttributeField">
    <optgroup label="Member Attribute">
        <option name="ageField">Age</option>
        <option name="birthdayField">Birthday</option>
        <option name="genderField">Gender</option>
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
        <option name="emailField">Email</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Membership (Status)"> 
        <option name="newMemberField">New</option>
        <option name="expiredMemberField">Expiration</option>
        ...,
        ...,
        <option name="renewMemberField">Renewed</option>
        </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Membership (General Activity)">
```

Answer (score 1):

It was helpful that you posted a picture of the output you're looking for.  I think I understand what you're looking to do.  Here's how I would do this (this is slightly simplified, but hopefully it gives you the picture):

```
var groups = [
    { name: 'Member Attributes', options: [
        { name: 'ageField', label: 'Age' },
        { name: 'birthdayField', label: 'Birthday' },
        { name: 'genderField', label: 'Gender' },
        //...
    ] },
    { name: 'Membership Status', options: [
        { name: 'newMembershipField', label: 'New Membership' },
        { name: 'expiredMemberField', label: 'Membership Expiration' },
        //...
    ] },
    { name: 'Member General Activity', options: [
        { name: 'lastFacilitiesEntryField', label: 'Last Facilities Entry' },
        { name: 'lastClassAttendance', label: 'Last Class Attendance' },
        //...
    ] },
    //...
];
```

I don't know how you're planning on transforming these structures to HTML, but here's how I would do it with jQuery:

```
groups.forEach(function(group){
     var $optgroup = $('<optgroup label="' + group.name + '">');
     group.options.forEach(function(option){
         $optgroup.append('<option name="' + option.name + '">' + 
             option.label + '</option>');
     });
     $('select').append($optgroup);
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u25TM/